# Is "develop to grow up" idiomatic?

Tags: idiomatic-language

I found two different versions of the essay question online. I asked my freelancer which one was correct. He responded that the second one was better. I want to know if **develop to grow up** is idiomatic. I know the essay question could be worded as "as they grow and develop". But I want to know if the freelancer was doing a good job by telling me that the second one was better.

> 1. Some people think watching TV is bad for children in every way. Others think it is good for **developing children as they grow up**.
>    Discuss both these views and give your own opinion.

> 2. Some people think watching TV is bad for children in every way. Others think TV has positive effects on children as they **develop to
>    grow up**. Discuss both these views and give your own opinion.

Comment: develop **and** grow up. Not "to".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If he told you the second one was better you should talk to someone else. Number 1 is the only we use normally. 'Developing children' is a bit of a set phrase where 'developing' is a modifier for 'children'; TV is not 'developing them to grow up'.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. By **'developing children' is a bit of a set phrase where 'developing' is a modifier for 'children'**, do you mean that "developing" acts like an adjective? I thought it was a verb.

Comment: @newbieforever Yes, much like 'a burning building'